# Systemverilog, How to extend a struct?

Tags: inheritance, struct, system-verilog

In synthesis-able RTL, if a set of packed struct extend one on another such as:

```
    typedef struct packed {
        logic .   a;
        logic .   b;
    } base_0_t;

    typedef struct packed {
        logic .   a;
        logic .   b;
        logic .   c;
    } base_1_t;

    typedef struct packed {
        logic .   a;
        logic .   b;
        logic .   c;
        logic .   d;
    } base_2_t;
```

One can do:

```
    typedef struct packed {
        base_0_t  t0;
        logic .   c;
    } base_1_t;

    typedef struct packed {
        base_1_t  t1;
        logic .   d;
    } base_2_t;
```

If one want to access 'a' in base_2_t, it must be written as: `base_2_t.t1.t0.a`. It quickly runs into a problem of easily lost in deep hierarchy.
Is there a way of access 'a' in the form of `base_2_t.a` and still have the benefit of extend base_0_t so that change in base_0_t can be inherited?

Answer (score 2):

There is no inheritance available when using a `struct`. A `class` is the only construct in SystemVerilog that supports inheritance, and classes have yet to be made synthesizable.